# ERROR: 'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'evaluate' is not a valid object reference.' when using TrasformFactory

Tags: java, xsl-fo, xpath, xalan

I am trying to transform an xsl + xml to xml (for later on transforming it into a pdf using FOP library).  The JDK I am using is 1.5, and there is no way I can use another (that is what the company I work in is using).  I read that the xalan jar of java 1.5 is the one responsible for the error.  The text that causes the error is:

```
"dyn:evaluate($xpath)"/>
```

in:

```
  <xsl:variable name="paramName" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="xpath"
      select="concat('/doc/data/',$paramName)" /> 
      <fo:inline>
        <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate($xpath)"/>
      </fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>
```

is there a way arround it without changing the jar?  Is there a way to write it differently? or am I using the wrong syntax?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

[`evaluate()`](http://www.exslt.org/dyn/index.html) is an EXSLT extension function.  It is non-standard, but many XSLT processors, [including xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/lib/ExsltDynamic.html), support it.

Have you declared the `dyn` namespace prefix in your stylesheet, so that it correctly references the EXSLT dynamic namespace?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
                extension-element-prefixes="dyn">

...

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry to resuscitate this dead thread; I have the same issue.  Declaring the namespace correctly does not resolve the issue FWIW.

Comment: @Laird Nelson - I just (re)verified that it works for me. Do you get an error, or just not producing the result you expect? Double check that you also have `extension-element-prefixes="dyn"` and that your XPath expression is correct. Maybe post a small example and ask as a question to get a second pair of eyes?

Comment: The issue is that the default implementation of `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` produces a `Transformer` that under the covers uses the Xalan XSLTC _compiler_, not _interpreter_, and `dyn` in this case is not supported.  See https://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions_xsltc.html#exslt_ext.